# Auth Failure in Form

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Rails has generated this action url for my form:

```
<form action="/auth/failure?action=update&controller=users"...
```

I'm authenticated to the website, even If I shouldn't be, it would redirect somewhere as I understand Auth.

My Form code:

```
<%= form_for @user, :url => { 'controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'update'} do |f| %>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is two thing you have to know

- Ruby makes difference between symbols (`:controller`, `:update`) and strings (`'controller'`, `'update'`).
- You do not need to specify `:url` in this case.

So, for your current code, the correct line is simple:

```
form_for @user do |f|
```

If `@user` is a new record, `form_for` will point to `create` action of your `UsersController`, if `@user` is an existing record, `form_for` will point to `update` action automatically. Rails is smart enough to do this :-)

If you really want to use `:url` attribute of `form_for`, you have two option:

- Use routing helper methods: `form_for @user, :url => user_path(@user), :method => :put`
- Use a correct path hash: `form_for @user, :url => { :controller => :users, :method => :update, :id => @user.id }`

Rails uses REST style for building urls if you use `resources :users` in `config/route.rb` (and I recommend you to use that), and it have two thing you need to know:
 - **Collection** is a group of entities (in your case, users)
 - **Member** is one entity

So collection URL is something where you can expect multiple entities, member URL is something where you can expect only one entity.

You must use `:id` when you describe `update` action with URL-hash, because `update` can done only on member, not on collection. So you have to build a member URL with a special HTTP method (`PUT`) to clarify, what do you want to do.